# How to copy specific subfolder from directory usin poweshell

Tags: powershell, copy, subdirectory, azure-artifacts, shfileoperation

Path1: D:\TestFolder\1001\TestSubFolder1\TestSubFolder2\

Path2: D:\TestFolder

How to copy TestSubFolder2(with inside contents) of the path1 to path2?

Note: In path1 the folder 1001 is a dynamic name, it always gets change so can not use full directory.
"D:\TestFolder" is a fixed directory in path1

Below is the one example to copy files
Copy-Item -Path "D:\TestFolder\1001\TestSubFolder1\TestSubFolder2\ *" -Destination "D:\TestFolder"

But the source directory is not fixed as 1001 folder name will be changed whenever build the code.

Comment: So where at in your code are you having trouble with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use a wildcard `*` instead of `1001` then?